# CSS inline-grid, problem matching image and text content heights

Tags: css, css-grid, responsive

I'm trying to use CSS `inline-grid` to create a layout with a circular image (using `border-radius: 50%` to create the circle) next to a block of text. The text uses `clamp` on the `font-size` so it's responsive, so depending on viewport width it might look larger or smaller.

The goal is to get the image height to match the height of the text, but remain a circle. Two equal height columns, in other words, but one containing just an image.

I've tried two different approaches, and neither quite gets the results I want.

The first version uses `object-fit: cover` and you can see my CodePen here: https://codepen.io/anwarmontasir/pen/KKJdBop.

```
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 0 1rem;
}
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

The problem is the image doesn't remain a circle. The heights of the 2 columns match, but depending on viewport width the image sometimes turns oval-shaped, like parts of the image are getting cropped.

---

The second version uses `aspect-ratio: 1` and you can see my CodePen here: https://codepen.io/anwarmontasir/pen/GRzpBqB

```
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 0 1rem;
}
.img-wrap {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  height: 100%;
}
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

Here, the behavior is more like what I want–the heights of the columns match, and the image remains a circle. However, depending on viewport width, the 2 columns sometimes overlap each other.

Thanks for your help, I've tried so many solutions and can't get this working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a minmax to stop your the grid columns from becoming too small (as seen in your second codepen). By changing the container class grid-template-columns to `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(350px, 1fr));` the columns won't go smaller than 350px, or whichever value you choose.

Another option, of course is to use flexbox as it's a bit more suited to this kind of work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, flexbox seems more logical, but I can't seem to force the image height to match the text content height in the second column using flexbox either.  


`minmax` is helpful but I'm still having issues adjusting the height of the image to match the second column's content height, then adjusting the width of the first column to respect the new height.  


In the meantime I've solved it using JavaScript.